# Is clojure.spec check generating bad input?

Tags: testing, clojure, clojure.spec, test.check, generative-testing

Using [clojure.spec](https://clojure.org/about/spec) (`org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.520"}`), I have a function spec that specifies a map for its input.

`gen/generate` and `gen/sample` work fine. But calling `cljs.spec.test.alpha/check` errors with input that should be a map, but is passed a collection (`Error: More than one element found in structure`). Ie, it looks like the spec system is generating bad input.

Is this a bug with spec?

> bar spec

```
(s/def ::check-run
  (s/keys
    :req-un
    [::action
     ::check_run
     ::installation
     ::organization
     ::repository
     ::sender]))
```

> foo.cljs

```
(s/def ::payload :bar/check-run)
(s/def ::check-run-started (s/keys :req-un [::payload]))

(s/fdef check-run->cijob-created
  :args (s/cat :arg ::check-run-started))

(defn check-run->cijob-created [arg])
```

While the function spec only declares A, the spec system is generating B.

```
;; A
{:payload {:action "", :check_run {:html_url "", }}, ...}

;; B
[({:payload {:action "", :check_run {:html_url "", }}, ...}})]
```

> workbench

```
(cljs.spec.test.alpha/check
  `foo/check-run->cijob-created
  {:clojure.spec.test.check/opts {:num-tests 10}})


[{:spec #object[cljs.spec.alpha.t_cljs$spec$alpha50916],

  :clojure.spec.test.check/ret
  {:shrunk
   {:total-nodes-visited 313, :depth 148, :pass? false, :result #object[Error Error: More than one element found in structure: 0], :result-data #:clojure.test.check.properties{:error #object[Error Error: More than one element found in structure: 0]}, :time-shrinking-ms 11299,
    :smallest
    [({:payload {:action "", :check_run {:html_url "", }}, ...}})]},

  :sym foo/check-run->cijob-created,
  :failure #object[Error Error: More than one element found in structure: 0]}]


  [1]: https://clojure.org/about/spec
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured this one out. It was failing due to my use of a [specter macro](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter/wiki/List-of-Macros#select-one) (with navigators). I’m not sure how. But somehow this messes up test.check generators. I’m assuming it’s some kind of strange interplay that’s unworkable with Clojurescript’s macro system.

Anyways, migrating to a simpler `get-in` fixed the problem.